# naxam mapbox for xamarin.forms nuget package doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mapbox, nuget-package

a freshly started xamarin.forms usuall error for no reasons solved by deleting bin and obj folders and rebuilding solution now everything should be perfect ... i type this in package manager :

Install-Package Naxam.Mapbox.Forms -Version 1.0.5.2
and it gives me this error :

Install-Package : NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment. Reference the package 
directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 formsMAPapp.Android -> Naxam.Mapbox.Forms 1.0.5.2 -> Naxam.Mapbox.Droid 6.4.0.1 -> 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment (>= 27.0.2.1) 
 formsMAPapp.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment (= 
25.4.0.2).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Naxam.Mapbox.Forms -Version 1.0.5.2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: I mean it tells you the problem, there is an existing package that has a conflicting dependency. Any reason why you aren't adding it via the nuget package manager within Visual Studio?

Comment: i am actually adding it with the nuget package manager , and i dont understand what dependancy are conflincting and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

so after a whole day of batteling with the versions of xamarin components and trying to update each one of them i needed to update Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment wich depended on a higher version of if i remember correctly Xamarin.Android.Support wich depended also on a higher version of other components none of them i could update so i figured i just have to update visual studio xDD pretty easy ... then what i did is installed each one of mapbox dependency from the nuget package manager